# How can I disable texture tiling on the x axis, leaving only the y axis?

Tags: uv, vector-mapping

[image]

[image]

Hi. I can't find a solution to an elementary function for 2 days.
Can you help me?

How can I disable texture tiling on the x axis, leaving only the y axis?

Comment: it's not clear to me from your sketches what you want to achieve. The way I understand it, after disabling the horizontal tiling, most of your mesh would be solid black, because it would go outside the $x$ ($u$ in the UV space) range of the image.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how your object is mapped. If its mapping is nicely aligned to one of the axes, you would just take some function of that axis to map a range, or a series of ranges, from 0-1 in that axis.

[image]

Here, in the simplest possible example, the image fills the 0-1 UV space, is scaled to 0-5, X and Y, in the geometry's space, tiled. The X range from `Value` to `Value+1` is mapped from 0-1, and clamped, so everything to the left is 0 and everything to the right is 1.

Changing `Value` maps different X-ranges from 0-1:

[image]

..moving the column of texture-repeats.

If your case is more complicated, maybe you could share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

There's no automatic way to prevent that, but you can easily do what you want to do. Select the faces where you don't want to see your pattern:

[image]

Then scale down their UVs in the *UV Editor* and move them until it's over the background and not the pattern anymore:

[image]

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, this will not solve the problem. It doesn't matter what to scale, texture or polygon. Since the tile is square, the scaling also takes place in a square. I need to get a small drawing and, accordingly, in any case, the repetition of the texture along the x-axis will occur. But I don't need it.
In the case as you advise, you need to split the polygon into another subdivide, and this is also not necessary.

Comment: is it possible to somehow disable the repetition on the x axis through the nodes?

Comment: Maybe but I'm not able to do it, maybe someone will know

Answer (score 0):

Decision. I used standard stitch tiling on both axes and a vertical mask without tiling.
[image]